# Optimizing results for query with WHERE EXISTS clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, exists

I have this table in postgres:

```
   id   |     id_datetime     |      longitude      |      latitude      
--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------
 639438 | 2018-02-20 18:00:00 |  -122.3880011217841 |  37.75538988423265
 639439 | 2018-02-20 20:30:00 | -122.38756878451498 | 37.760550220844614
 639440 | 2018-02-20 20:05:00 | -122.39640513677658 |  37.76130039041195
 639441 | 2018-02-24 10:00:00 | -122.45819139221014 | 37.724317534370066
 639442 | 2018-02-10 09:00:00 | -122.44693382058489 |  37.77000760474354
```

I want an output with all the differents ID's which has at least another ID between the last 15 minutes and between 1000 meters (geographic distance).

My table has more than 100K rows. So, I'm currently trying with the following query which works but takes too long. Are there any steps I can take to optimize this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.id
FROM table x
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.id <> x.id
    AND (t.id_datetime between x.id_datetime - interval '15 minutes' AND x.id_datetime)
    AND (ST_Distance((geography(ST_MakePoint(x.longitude, x.latitude))), 
        geography(ST_MakePoint(t.longitude, t.latitude)) ) <= 1000)
)
```

Comment: How are your tables indexed?  If they're not indexed, then that's where to start.  See https://use-the-index-luke.com for a good tutorial about why indexes matter.  Also, how long does the query take, and how long do you expect it to take?

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the index. I created one and the time really improved.

Comment: Then you can create a spatial index (and why not storing the geography directly at the same time) and use `ST_Dwithin` instead of `ST_Distance`, as the former can make use of the spatial index